# Can't build Visual Studio / Xamarin App

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and trying to build an Xamarin solution (Android and iOS app). I am getting the following errors that are resulting in a failed build:

C : error APT0000: \Dev\GYB\GYBMobile\GYBMobile\GYBMobile.Android\obj\Debug\lp\68\jl\res\values-v24\values-v24.xml:1: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
C : error APT0000: \Dev\GYB\GYBMobile\GYBMobile\GYBMobile.Android\obj\Debug\lp\68\jl\res\values-v24\values-v24.xml:1: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.

I cannot find any information on this. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can try to delete the bin folder in your project and build again

Comment: @EngSoonCheah, I have done that, I have removed all bin, obj folder as well as removed the packages folder to force a refresh to no avail.

Comment: What is  your compile version? Try to use Android 7.0( which is v24).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working by installing SDK platform 24.